# Drawing a normal curve in python

Tags: python, excel, normal-distribution

i have  seen a lot of  documentation about normal distribution  and  curve sketching in python and i am a bit confused about it, i Have generated normal random variables with  mean 30 and standard deviation 3.7 , and using function norm.dist i have  estimated pdf function

```
=NORM.DIST(A2,$H$2,$I$2,FALSE)
```

on the based of this formula, i sketched  scatter chart and i have got
[image]

i want for  demonstration purpose  sketch the same using python, i found scipy and numpy version, please help me    clarify things clearly, here are some set of my numbers

[image]

i have tried following code

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data_random =pd.read_excel("data_for_normal.xlsx")
data_values =data_random["NormalVariables"].values
pdf_values =norm.pdf(data_values,30,3.7)
plt.plot(data_values,pdf_values)
plt.title("normal curve")
plt.xlabel("x values")
plt.ylabel("probability density function")
plt.show()
```

but i have got
[image]

result of :

```
print(data_random.head(10))
 NormalVariables
0        29.214494
1        30.170595
2        36.014144
3        30.388626
4        28.398749
5        24.861042
6        29.519316
7        24.207164
8        35.779376
9        26.042977
```

Comment: so  most popular  way of saying i dont know answer is downvoting :D :D

Comment: Maybe https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy-stats-norm would help?

Comment: i found this one, just i  am confused about parameters

Comment: i found following code  using normal.pdf, but it does not work well

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) - How about including `data_random.head(10)`

Comment: ok but what about code?

Comment: i have posted result

Comment: use `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot`

Comment: ok but why plot does not work?

Comment: Add `data_values.sort()` **after** `data_values =data_random["NormalVariables"].values` ... https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# plt.plot connects datapoints with lines:

x = [0,1,2]
y = [1,4,3]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

```
#note that lines are drawn between adjacent elements in the list,
#so a line from (0,1) to (1,4) and then to (2,3)

# if the order of the datapoints is changed, the position of the datapoints 
# remains unchanged, but now lines are drawn between different points

x = [2,0,1]
y = [3,1,4]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

[image]

So the reason you see all the crisscrossing in your plot is that you plot unsorted data.

If you simply want to replicate the plot from excel, use `plt.scatter` instead. This plot just the datapoints and does not draw connections between them.

```
x = [2,0,1]
y = [3,1,4]
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

[image]